# is this a valid way of showing bijective function along with inverse of that function?

Tags: functions

$$f: X \to Y$$
$$\forall a \in X, \exists! b \in Y \colon f(a) = b$$

$$f^{-1} \colon Y \to X$$
$$f^{-1}(f(a)) = a$$

is possible to write bijective function and its inverse in one equation?

Comment: Alas, this is just a mass of symbols. Could you please explain, in words, exactly what you're aiming to do?

Comment: I want to say that function f is bijective and want to write its inverse.

Comment: How do I mathamatically demonstrate that function is bijective along with its inverse? For all real numbers.

Comment: The condition does not imply bijection. If however, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $\forall b\in Y,\exists ! a\in X$ satisfying $f(a)=b$ then the mapping is a bijection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition is not completely correct  $\forall a \in X, \exists !b \in Y : f(a) = b $ is a way of defining "injective". However a bijection is also surjective.  For bijective you have to have $\forall b \in Y \exists! a \in X : f(a) = b $.

In order for there to be an inverse not only does there have to be a unique element when you go from X to Y but also when you go back again.